# UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage nil causing crash on photo capture

Tags: ios

I am getting a crash in several versions of my apps, and it seems to have started happening on iOS8. I only experience it through crash reports and can't reproduce it on my test devices. It seems to be when a user captures an image (or selects it from the library?) and the original image cannot be set because the image is nil. The closest issue I can find while searching is this:

https://github.com/B-Sides/ELCImagePickerController/issues/58

Another possibility is when it is backgrounded with a specific race condition timing, which I'm also unable to reproduce.

http://openradar.appspot.com/19953748

but I don't think my error is coming from a stream image being selected. I'm hoping to see if anyone else is getting this error, and has either figured out a solution to consistently catch the exception, or detect when this happens, or disable a specific user action (like backgrounding the app while uploading photos) to avoid a crash.

Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)

```
Thread : Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x2b381fef __exceptionPreprocess + 126
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x39633c8b objc_exception_throw + 38
2  CoreFoundation                 0x2b29daa3 -[__NSDictionaryM setObject:forKey:] + 850
3  PhotoLibrary                   0x345bf8f3 __CreateInfoForImage
4  PhotoLibrary                   0x345bf1ad PLNotifyImagePickerOfImageAvailability
5  PhotoLibrary                   0x345d384b -[PLUICameraViewController cameraView:photoSaved:]
6  PhotoLibrary                   0x34606a73 -[PLImagePickerCameraView cropOverlay:didFinishSaving:]
7  PhotoLibrary                   0x3460706d -[PLImagePickerCameraView captureController:didCompleteResponse:forStillImageRequest:error:]
8  CameraKit                      0x303392a5 -[CAMCaptureController _completedResponse:forRequest:error:]
9  CameraKit                      0x30338bfb __56-[CAMCaptureController enqueueStillImageCaptureRequest:]_block_invoke_32160
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x39b9e2e3 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 10
11 libdispatch.dylib              0x39b9e2cf _dispatch_client_callout + 22
12 libdispatch.dylib              0x39ba1d2f _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1330
13 CoreFoundation                 0x2b347609 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 8
14 CoreFoundation                 0x2b345d09 __CFRunLoopRun + 1512
15 CoreFoundation                 0x2b292201 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 476
16 CoreFoundation                 0x2b292013 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 106
17 GraphicsServices               0x32b71201 GSEventRunModal + 136
18 UIKit                          0x2ea36a59 UIApplicationMain + 1440
19 Pact                           0x000b26ab main (main.m:17)
20 libdyld.dylib                  0x39bbfaaf start + 2
```

EDIT Sept 18, 2017 I have not revisited this issue and have not found a solution, unfortunately :(

Comment: "The closest issue I can find while searching is this". I have done a google search, and nothing relevant comes up. Thus, posting a question on stack overflow. Hopefully a google search will lead to this question.

Comment: Okay, I will google it _for_ you. For example, I found this: http://www.openradar.appspot.com/19953748 Quite insightful, I think.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I do remember seeing that one. Doesn't look like they have any responses or solutions, either. So, to follow up, and maybe my question needs to be reworded - does anyone have a solution to this? I have not been able to reproduce the crash in my app even while backgrounding.

Comment: "does anyone have a solution" Yes, that might be a better question. But don't expect an answer. I think all indications are that it's a bug at Apple's end. (You must have noticed already that UIImagePickerController is buggy in other ways too.)

Comment: Hey @mitrenegade I have the same exact issue (also on iOS 8 - haven't encountered it on iOS 9). Happens on crash reports but can't reproduce... Did you ever got the chance to solve this? Find out more about it?

Comment: no, haven't worked on this app for a while. it wasn't happening 100% of the time so we let it go.

Comment: @mitrenegade - did you turn on the flash while taking photos ?

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue now on iOS 10.

Comment: Hi @mitrenegade Perfectly reasonable place to ask a question, and indeed, a Google search does lead here now where I get the useful answer that this is something I can radar and ignore. I'm not really sure why "some people" in comments above seem to consider you, I and others finding that out from stack overflow to be "a bad thing that makes them grumpy and they need us to know that". Perhaps we could deduce things about those people from that attitude. Who knows.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to reproduce this crash from exactly the scenario based in http://openradar.appspot.com/19953748 . I set up an infinite loop that took a picture every 2 seconds and I continuously moved the app between background and foreground. It crashes with the same stack trace pretty quickly. Though I am not sure of the root cause for this I am able to resolve it by simply checking for application state before taking the picture

```
//Swift
if UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationState == .Active {
                // Take picture
}
```

Comment: I found that I can replicate this pretty much 100% of the time if the flashMode is set to On. Just hit the shutter button and then quickly hit the power button to lock the phone. If you're experiencing this, please file a Radar at https://bugreport.apple.com. Here's mine: https://openradar.appspot.com/28108858

Comment: @Kedar Hi, I've just discovered this same problem. Where exactly did you put your code? I still get the crash. I tried it in: func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        
        if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active {
             if let chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {..
        }

Answer (score 0):

```
  If you write tap gesture or action sheet,just check the below code with your code. 

 -(void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
  {
     UIImagePickerController *pickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];
     pickerController.delegate=self;
     if(buttonIndex==0)
     {
         pickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
         [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
     }
     else if(buttonIndex==1)
     {
         if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera] == YES)
        {
            NSLog(@"Camera is available and ready");
            pickerController.sourceType=UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [self presentViewController:pickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"Camera is not available");
            [[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Whoa !" message:@"Camera is not available" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil]show];
        }
    }

  }
```

Then in delegate method,

```
   -(void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
   {

       UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:@"UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage"];
       imageView.image = image;
       [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
   }
```

Comment: The exception seems to be happening when info is being populated with the image; in the stack trace, the crash happens because the camera framework is trying to set the value of the key UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage to nil. I'm trying to understand why an image that we've picked can be nil - it don't think it's a memory issue since all the crash reports don't indicate a memory warning.

Comment: @mitrenegade have you find the cause of it and any solution?

Comment: i havent revisited this. the last thing i remember is it may have to do with loading cloud photos. unfortunately no answer despite matt's help (/s)

Comment: Does my above coding is helpful for you?

Comment: @mitrenegade is there any solution for this crash issue, I am also facing nil issue, please advice

Comment: @mitrenegade is there any solution for this crash issue, I am also facing nil issue, please advice                                                                       
                                                                                                             **Latest Session (3 days ago) Download .txtView all sessions
Fatal Exception: NSInvalidArgumentException
*** setObjectForKey: object cannot be nil (key: UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage)